# How to use active record query with symbols and operators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Could this be converted to use symbols and operators notation instead for better readability:

```
  scope :visible, where("is_hidden = false")
  scope :current, where("exp_date IS NULL OR exp_date > " + timestamp)
```

**Convert** into something like this:

```
scope :active, where(   :is_hidden => false,
                        (:exp_date => nil || :exp_date > timestamp)
                    )
```

Sorry for the screwed up syntax (I'm brand new to ruby)

Comment: Check Squeel https://github.com/ernie/squeel

Comment: What does the "Build Status: FAILING" on their GitHub mean? Is it a safe gem to be utilizing?

Comment: Squeel is awesome. If you're using pre-3.1 and having issues you might check out [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where)...same people/person I believe.

Comment: Squeel seems to work great! Now if someone could just put this as an answer so I could close it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda feel like I'm stealing the glory from the people commenting your question, but here's a possible solution as well:

With [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel), you could write your scopes something like this:

```
def self.active
  where{!is_hidden}
end

def self.current(timestamp)
  where{exp_date.nil? | exp_date > timestamp}
end
```